# Cloning file attributes in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to clone folders with their contents using a small python script, but I am facing a little problem - when I copy, for example, a hidden or a system file, the copied file loses those attributes.

I know that I can get the file attributes by using either the `os.stat(original_file).st_file_attributes` or the `win32api.GetFileAttributes(original_file)` and also that I can use `win32api.SetFileAttributes()` to set the attributes for the target file if, for example, I test for the `stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.

The problem is that I don't know of a direct way of using the full result of the `win32api.GetFileAttributes()` in the `win32api.SetFileAttributes()`. By full result I mean all the file attributes at once.

To be clearer, what I want to achieve is:

1. Get the file attributes from the `original_file`.
2. Set the file attributes to the `target_file`.

Is this possible in one go or to I have to test individually for each file attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you very much for your quick replies. You got me thinking a bit more... Long story short, I was being dumb! What I want (to clone the file attributes) can be simply achieved like this:

```
import win32api

file1 = 'D:\\_test_fs1\\file1.txt' # hidden and system file (attrib +h +s file1.txt)
file2 = 'D:\\_test_fs2\\copy_of_file1.txt' # non-hidden and non-system file (attrib -h -s copy_of_file1.txt)

f1a = win32api.GetFileAttributes(file1)
f2a = win32api.GetFileAttributes(file2)

if f1a == f2a:
    print('The files have the same attributes (f1: %i) (f2: %i).' % (f1a, f2a))
    print('Nothing to do.')
else:
    print('The files DO NOT have the same attributes (f1: %i) (f2: %i)!' % (f1a, f2a))
    win32api.SetFileAttributes(file2, f1a) # Setting file2 to have the same exact attributes as file1
    print('Attributes in f2 set.')
```

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

There is this command called `attrib`. It adds the attributes to the file.

```
attrib <attributes> <file directory>
```

You can add attributes using this format:

```
'+h' makes file hidden
'+r' makes file read only
```

And so on.

So we would use it like this to make the file hidden and read only
`attrib  +h +r <file directory>`

So put all the attributes you have in the list in the format for the `attrib` command. Execute the command with `os.system()`.

Comment: Linking to outside resources risks information being lost to link rot in short order. Can you include the important parts in the body of your answer?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: It's complete. I'm a little leery of recommending calls to outside processes though. Also, `os.system` is a bad idea for several reasons (security, stability, etc.; whitespace and shell metacharacters are a danger with arbitrary file names); `subprocess.check_call` (*without* `shell=True`) is safer.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are suggesting an external call and even so it isn't really cloning the attributes from one file to another, it is just setting some specific attributes in a file. What I want is to set, in one go, the target file with the same exact attributes that exist in the source file - get and then set.